# How to transfer the local database of wpf application from one computer to other?

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I have created a local database in my WPF application,now i want to run the application on some other computer,now how to transfer the  local database from one computer to other,and i dont want to create the database manually on other machine? Do we have to convert the database into some .exe file ? If yes,then how to do this or what is the best approach to implement this?
My application accesses its own database file in its own directory with this connection string:

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Data\" + databaseFileName;
```

Please explain from scratch as i am new to this??

Comment: Which Db tool do you use? MS SQL? Automatic DB replication is not easy as you describe.

Comment: If I understand your question (you need a copy, not a replica): according to database engine you're using backup+restore or just a file copy. BTW don't build path like that, use Path.Append().

Comment: Could you add the `db` file into your application resources and select always copy?

Comment: my local database extension is .sdf and i am using sql

Comment: If it is MS SQL, pull it out as script and rerun the script in another machine...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're running your database in SQL Express. You can use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) (included in most SQL Server installers) to export your database, including data, to a `.bacpac` file.

In SQL Server Management Studio 2012, right click your database, select **Tasks**, then **Export Data-tier Application...** and go through the wizard.

Then connect SQL Server Management Studio to the SQL Express server of the target machine. You can do that by connecting Management Studio on your machine to the SQL Express running on the target machine (provided that a network connection exists between the two, and the target machine has been properly configured to accept the connection), or by also installing Management Studio on the target machine, then connecting it to the local server (`.\sqlexpress`).

Once connected, right click the **Databases** in the **Object Explorer**, select **Import Data-tier application...**, and go through the wizard.

Comment: i have created local database by right clicking on my solution and a=then i added local database in wpf and i am using normal sql queries for functioning

Comment: I think you need to create some kind of installation package (e.g., a self-extracting executable), that includes your database (`.sdf`), then install that on the target machine.
You might also consider reading [this blog post](http://bembengarifin-tech.blogspot.be/2008/08/generate-script-export-data-from-sql-ce.html).